# Parameter of type Func2 in QObject::connect?

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, qt5, signals-slots

`QObject::connect` takes parameters as following:

```
connect(const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal,
        const QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object *receiver, Func2 slot);
```

Now let's say I'm creating a method `QPushButton *newPushButton(const QString &text, Func2 slot);`, how do I use the `Func2` as a parameter's type, do I have to include something?

Here's an example of how I'd like my `newPushButton` to look like:

```
QPushButton *MyWidget::newPushButton(const QString &text, Func2 slot)
{
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(text);
    layout->addWidget(pushButton);
    QObject::connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, slot);
    return pushButton;
}
```

And now I could call it like so:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
{
    layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    myButton1 = newPushButton("My Button One", &MyWidget::on_myButton1_clicked);
    myButton2 = newPushButton("My Button Two", &MyWidget::on_myButton2_clicked);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass `&MyWidget::slot` as a parameter to the `newPushButton()` method without using templates (how does `connect()` do it?).

`layout` and both `myButton`s are members of `MyWidget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass &MyWidget::slot as a parameter to the newPushButton() method without using templates (how does connect() do it?).

I don't get it -- those connect() overloads use templates: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h.html#212

Can't you just do the very same?

```
template<typename Func2> 
QPushButton *MyWidget::newPushButton(const QString &text, Func2 slot)
{
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(text);
    layout->addWidget(pushButton);
    QObject::connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, slot);
    return pushButton;
}
```

Comment: Oh... I feel really silly now. How is it that I can call `connect(...)` instead of `connect<QPushButton, MyWidget>(...)`?

Comment: Because template arguments for functions may get deducted by the compiler (and they are in this case), see §14.8.2.1 of the [C++11 Standard](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard). If you think about it, you do write `qMax(5, 12)`, not `qMax<int>(5, 12)`; you write `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())`, not `std::sort<vector::iterator>(v.begin(), v.end())`, etc.

Comment: Awesome, how come I didn't know that... Is it only in C++11, cause I've never used C++11 before, only the 98 version? :P

Comment: Actually it's C++98. It's just that the PDF of N3337 (i.e. C++11 + editorial fixes) is freely available at the address above, so I quote from it and you can cross check the references. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the signal you're using is `clicked()` (without the parameter of type `bool`?), it's type is `void(*)()` so you can just replace `Func2 slot` with `void(*slot)()`:

```
QPushButton *MyWidget::newPushButton(const QString &text, void(*slot)())
{
    QPushButton *pushButton = new QPushButton(text);
    layout->addWidget(pushButton);
    QObject::connect(pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked,
                     this, slot);
    return pushButton;
}
```

Comment: Nope, `Func2` is of type `void(MyWidget::*)()`. But I can't use that, since I want to generalize it just like in `connect`. I could of course make my `newPushButton` a template method, but there has to be an easier way, since `connect` uses `Func2`.